# Finding first place in nested list where some member doesn't exist

Tags: r, list, traversal

Suppose I have a list like

```
li <- list( 
        mammals = list( 
          giraffe = list(
            name       = 'giraffe',
            occupation = 'giraffing' ),
          bear = list(
            name       = 'bear' )
          ),
        amphibians = list(
          frog = list(
            name       = 'frog',
            occupation = 'frogging' ),
          snake = list(
            name       = 'snake' )
          )
         )
```

Notice that `bear` and `snake` don't have an `occupation` element. I want to traverse my list on this level of nesting (depth 2) and return the first (or any) member which doesn't have an `occupation` member. So in this case, suitable return values for my function would be

```
li$mammals$bear
```

or

```
li$amphibians$snake
```

**To summarize, my question is** how can I traverse on a nested depth level and return an element based on a condition in a list like this?

---

I'm not at all versed in R, but I believe I figured out how to determine whether each list element at my depth of interest (2) has the members I want to ensure exist recursively with something like

```
required <- c('name', 'occupation')

has_elems <- function(ob, 
                      cur_d=0)
    ifelse(is.list(ob),
           all(sapply(ob, has_elems, cur_d=cur_d+1)),
           cur_d != 2 || all(required %in% names(ob)))
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to most easily perform the traversal if my intention isn't to just return `TRUE` or `FALSE` but instead the first false condition as outlined above, though.

Note that this is a toy example - I'm actually trying to validate some user input data before database entry, and this is pretty representative of my problem I think.

Comment: Please check your input example.  It is giving errors

Comment: @akrun My apologies, I had an extra comma in there. Should be good now I think.

Comment: Try `lapply(li, function(x)  Filter(length, sapply(x, function(nm) nm[!"occupation" %in% names(nm)])))[1]`

Comment: @akrun That _nearly_ works, I think. It works for my particular input, but suppose that `bear` does have an occupation.. it then just returns an empty list and does not return `snake` as it should. I'm trying to work off of it now though.

Comment: I guess in that case, a double `Filter` is required, i.e. `Filter(length, lapply(l2, function(x)  Filter(length, sapply(x, function(nm) nm[!"occupation" %in% names(nm)]))))`

Comment: @akrun Appears to work, thank you. I'm just wrapping my head around it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the nested `list` with `lapply`, subset the elements based on logical condition `%in%`, `Filter` the NULL elements of `list`

```
Filter(length, lapply(li, function(x) Filter(length, 
       lapply(x, function(nm) nm[!"occupation" %in% names(nm)]))))
```